# What is the meaning in of this PHP line '<<<XML <!--xml tags here --> XML' i can;t seem to parse this right

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have this php line in magento rest api for inserting a product image. It works but I need to know whats happening because it causes error sometimes parsing. thanks

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<magento_api>
<file_mime_type>image/jpeg</file_mime_type
<file_content>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAWtJREFUeNpi/P//P8NgBkwMgxyMOnDUgTDAyMhIDNYF4vNA/B+IDwCxHLoakgEoFxODiQRXQUYi4e3k2gfDjMRajsP3zED8F8pmA+JvUDEYeArEMugOpFcanA/Ef6A0CPwC4uNoag5SnAjJjGI2tKhkg4rLAfFGIH4IxEuBWIjSKKYkDfZCHddLiwChVhokK8YGohwEZYy3aBmEKmDEhOCgreomo+VmZHxsMEQxIc2MAx3FO/DI3RxMmQTZkI9ALDCaSUYdOOrAIeRAPzQ+PxCHUM2FFDb5paGNBPRa5C20bUhxc4sSB4JaLnvxVHWHsbVu6OnACjyOg+HqgXKgGRD/JMKBoD6LDb0dyAPE94hwHAw/hGYcujlwEQmOg+EV9HJgLBmOg+FMWjsQVKR8psCBoDSrQqoDSSmoG6Hpj1wA6ju30LI9+BBX4UsC+Ai0T4BWVd1EIL5PgeO+APECmoXgaGtm1IE0AgABBgAJAICuV8dAUAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=
</file_content>
<file_name>test</file_name>
</magento_api>
XML;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax - the lines between `<<<XML` and `XML;` are treated as a string value.

It can be useful if you want to ignore quotation issues (mixed `'` and `"`) and is often picked up by syntax highlighting (`TXT`, `SQL`, `HTML` are also common identifiers.)

Parsing errors are often caused by ignoring the following warning:

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing
>   identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;).
>   That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and
>   there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.
>   It's also important to realize that the first character before the
>   closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating
>   system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing
>   delimiter must also be followed by a newline.

Comment: Thank you for a very informing answer :)